# How can I prevent changes to existing files but allow creation of files in a git repo?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm assuming a server-side git hook will be at least part of the solution, but I'm not seeing a way to *allow creation* but *prevent modification* of files.

The use-case here is "migration" scripts for tracking database schema changes, so the files will be limited to a particular type in a particular part of the directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to simply check for the type of changes using `git diff-index --cached HEAD`. This will show you which files are being changed and the type of change being made:

```
>>> git diff-index --cached HEAD
:100644 000000 dadd545e60815b2c9870d06949fec14698d70eef 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      a-deleted-file
:100644 100644 b13f8d4cd9f0aa4d12a07326bdcd8ff9ce3d04fa 0eb9b914fc18b8f5db13d095f95657c6dedd40ab M      a-modified-file
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 96081681f18aaa7a70ed5d59549098a2685684e4 A      a-new-file
```

So you can parse this output for the change type field: `git diff-index | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -f 1`. This will give you a list of the type of changes being made:

```
D
M
A
```

And you can simply check for any modifications or deletions and exit the hook if any "disallowed" change was made to tracked files:

```bash
if git diff-index | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -f 1 | grep --quiet '[M|D]'; then
    echo 'files can only be added, not deleted or modified'
    exit 1
fi
```